# ERROR "must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Tags: sql, group-by, orderby, maxima

Estoy intentando juntar desde 3 tablas distintas, nombre, apellido y salario más alto de los 5 empleados que tenga el titulo de 'Ingineer', sin que se repitan los nombres. Esto es lo que vengo intentando

```
SELECT MAX(s.salary),
e.first_name,
e.last_name
FROM public.employees e
JOIN public.titles t ON (e.emp_no = t.emp_no)
JOIN public.salaries s ON (e.emp_no = s.emp_no)
WHERE t.title = 'Engineer'
GROUP BY e.emp_no
ORDER BY s.salary DESC
LIMIT 5
```

La consulta va bien hasta el GROUP BY, quedando así;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, cuando quiero ordenarlo con ORDER BY para conseguir los mayores 5 salarios me sale el error del título, el siguiente;
"ERROR:  column "s.salary" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 9:  ORDER BY s.salary DESC"

Luego probé con la siguiente con la siguiente consulta, que me recomendaron en los comentarios;

```
SELECT q.*
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT(s.salary),
e.first_name,
e.last_name
FROM public.employees e
JOIN public.titles t ON (e.emp_no = t.emp_no)
JOIN public.salaries s ON (e.emp_no = s.emp_no)
WHERE t.title = 'Engineer'
GROUP BY e.emp_no, s.salary) AS q
ORDER BY q.salary DESC
limit 5
```

Pero me sigue apareciendo un empleado dos veces. Dándome como resultado la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya pude resolver la consulta. Modifiqué lo siguiente, cambié el GROUP BY quitando s.salary y solo dejé e.emp.no y e.last_name, así mismo saqué SELECT DISTINCT Y utilicé un Aggregation, MAX(), para que me permita usar ORDER BY por salario, pero solo me dejó hacerlo una vez que le puse un nombre a la columna de salarios 'R', dejándome la siguiente consulta con el resultado;

```
SELECT q.*
FROM(SELECT MAX(s.salary) AS R,
e.first_name,
e.last_name
FROM public.employees e
JOIN public.titles t ON (e.emp_no = t.emp_no)
JOIN public.salaries s ON (e.emp_no = s.emp_no)
WHERE t.title = 'Engineer'
GROUP BY e.emp_no, e.last_name) AS q
ORDER BY q.R DESC
limit 5
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y por que no le haces caso al error ?? Dice que agregues s.salary al GROUP BY

Comment: Ese link manda a wsp, pasa un link de imagten mejor

Comment: tendría que ser `GROUP BY e.emp_no, e.first_name,e.last_name`

Comment: @Excorpion cuando hago eso me sale una misma persona dos veces, no se agrupa, quedado así:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1amdNhdnDeCSY1ZYN7AT9_aNVc9qVhXL7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @lsanchezo lo he probado y me queda igual, el nombre y apellido Bernardo Sinitsyn sigue repitiendose.

Comment: es que bernardo tiene seguramente dos registros en los que el max() identifica al mayor, pero lo "pinta" en ambos registros, en todo caso en tu select coloca distinct... `select distinct...`, otro método es usando el group by de manera más eficiente.

Comment: @lsanchezo Sí, tiees razón en eso, Bernardo tiene dos registros máximos, probé también con select Distinct y me sigue apareciendo dos veces ¿A qué te refieres con manera más eficiente?

Comment: la consulta principal la puedes extraer y luego le aplicas el order by: `SELECT q.* from(consultaPrincipal) as q order by q.Salario desc`

Comment: @Arriel Hola, gracias por la ayuda, se sigue repitiendo la misma persona, te muestro la consulta que escribí y el resultado, por si no te entendí, ya que soy bastante nuevo en esto.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ri5RCre1fB3SInlS5iWZ-Y0bon98-IeE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: En lugar de dirigirnos a tu drive, por qué no editas tu pregunta y añades lo que has intentado y el resultado?

Comment: @Arriel Ahí lo hice, gracias por la sugerencia, no estoy acostumbrado a la página.